# Angular 9 - universal + express-engine

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I was using universal on Angular 8 and everything was working great but I have some troubles with the new version

It seems like it's no longer possible to use the ngExpressEngine without compiling the server.ts with the angular app. You could totally do it before.

I have a huge codebase written in js for my express server, and I cannot compile it with my angular application like the thing is set with the schematics. From the basic setup you just compile everything together and then `node ../dist/myapp/server/main.js` which launch your "universal" server.

So what I wish I could do is to build my server side angular app without the server.ts and then use the build when I need it with the ngExpressEngine, from my main application

=========================================================================

edit for David answer

```
require("zone.js/dist/zone-node");
const { ngExpressEngine } = require("@nguniversal/express-engine");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { join } = require("path");
const { AppServerModule } = require("./dist/ttmodel/server/main");
const { existsSync } = require("fs");
const { APP_BASE_HREF } = require("@angular/common");

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "dist")));

const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), "dist/ttmodel/browser");
const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, "index.original.html"))
  ? "index.original.html"
  : "index";

app.engine(
  "html",
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  })
);

app.set("view engine", "html");
app.set("views", distFolder);

app.get(
  "*.*",
  express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: "1y",
  })
);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, {
    req,
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }],
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

you mean something like that ? I tried but it doesn't work I end up with

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app.component.html'
```

on the original server.ts you import AppServerModule directly from './src/main.server'

I tried to use `renderModule` and `renderModuleFactory` from `@angular/platform-server` but I couldn't make it works either.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to improve my question

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong (and I haven't tested this), but I think you can just import whetever you need in your own server from the compiled angular server bundle.

If you look at the bottom of a default `server.ts`, you can see these lines.

```
// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

So if you just compile `server.ts` using angular 9 new way of doing it, you end of with a `main.js` file. You can just `require` that `main.js` bundle in your own code and you can get `AppServerModule` out of it and use it in your own code

```
const {AppServerModule} = require('./dist/server/main');
```

Comment: Thank, I tried but didn't work unfortunately, I updated my question to show you what I tested

Comment: Yes, your edit is what I had in mind. I'll give it a go tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, that would be amazing if you can find a way, I tried everything for three days. The documentation is limited for universal but even on the official @angular/platform-server side there is pretty much nothing.

Comment: I just quickly tried and got a different error than yours. Don't have the time to investigate right now. Would that help with your scenario? https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1363

Comment: Well, thank you for trying, yes if I had the AppServerModuleNgFactory that would solve my problem, but it’s not in the export of the server build and the issue doesn’t go anywhere. I managed to make it work with a server dedicated to universal but honestly, it’s so ugly.

Comment: Actually, this issue helped a lot the last comment unlocked me

Comment: Yes that's the one I was referring too, sorry. Did not get a chance to try it or understand why this is necessary though